# Previous and next link with url in array

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

Here's my php code

```
<?php
$pageOK = array('page0' => 'page0.php',
                  'page1' => 'content1.php',
                  'page2' => 'anotherContent2.php',
                  'page3' => 'anotherpagewithotherlink.php',
                  'page4' => 'blablabla.php',
                  'page5' => 'bleh.php',
                  'page6' => 'foo.php',
                  'page7' => 'bar.php');


  if ( (isset($_GET['projet'])) && (isset($pageOK[$_GET['projet']])) ) {
    include($pageOK[$_GET['projet']]);   
  } 
?>
```

This will make in sort that "index.php?project=page0" will load in the url with mod_rewrite enable (http://www.example.com/page0/)

Note that the url is different. My question is how I can make a Prev / Next link to go to the next or previous array and if it's the first hide the Prev link and for the last hide the Next link.

Comment: My question is how I can make a Prev / Next link to go to the next or previous array and if it's the first hide the Prev link and for the last hide the Next link. Can't you read it ??? It's the last line !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($pageOK as $key => $val){
    if($key == $_GET['projet']){
        $next = key($pageOK);
        break;
    }
    $prev = $key;
}
```

`$next` and `$prev` holds the array keys.

Comment: YEAH that's it, that's what I wanted just need some tweaks.

Comment: I've noted that when it reach the last array, it loops the first one, any way to hide the $next when it's the last array ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, just get the number from the $_GET['project'] and decrease/increase should be what you want. And if you change the 'page0' to just a number '0' it simplify this problem.

Comment: Yeah but the url will be now http://www.example.com/0/ which it's bad because I want to replace those page0 to page7 with keywords like http://www.example.com/programs/ or http://www.example.com/content/, etc...

Comment: so do a array of possibles pages and check the page (www.example.com/page) if it's in the array and if it will be then iclude it and so you dont have to have a associative array

Answer (score 0):

so.. actually this is bad structure. You can put your array to common file like pages.php and on each page include it. So example for page0.php

```
require_once ('pages.php');
$page_name = 'bar.php';
$key = array_search($page_name, $pageOK);

if ($key !== FALSE)
{
    $key_arr = array_keys($pageOK);
    $index = array_search($key, $key_arr);
    if (!empty($index))
    {
      buildLink($key_arr[$index-1], 'Prev page');
    }
    if ($index !== count($key_arr)-1)
    {
            buildLink($key_arr[$index+1], 'Next page');
    }

}
```

code for pages.php

```
$pageOK = array('page0' => 'page0.php',
                  'page1' => 'content1.php',
                  'page2' => 'anotherContent2.php',
                  'page3' => 'anotherpagewithotherlink.php',
                  'page4' => 'blablabla.php',
                  'page5' => 'bleh.php',
                  'page6' => 'foo.php',
                  'page7' => 'bar.php');

function buildLink($page, $anchor)
{
  if (isset($pageOK($page)))
  {
    print '<a href="$root_url.$page">'.$anchor.'</a>';
  }
}
```

But much better if you move array of page to db and create page controller